# Widget tracking total contributions

Tags: civicontribute

I'd like to have a widget track all contributions on the site but it appears that is not possible as each widget is tied to a contribution page. Is there any custom code anyone has developed to do this?

Alternatively, I've just done a work around solution that is not that optimal. I could manually switch the "Online Contrubution Page" it is under by going to Edit Contributions>Additional details. The one concern I have is would this have any adverse effect on paypal monthly recurring donations? Would PayPal and CiviCRM still communicate properly?

Thanks all, this is my first post to the forum though I've been using CiviCRM for a few years.

Comment: What do you mean by widget? Is it only show the total amount the donor has contributed? Or has it any additional functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but these extensions may help:

1) CiviStats: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civistats
2) CiviWCI: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civiwci

Answer (score 0):

You can use civicrm api to display report. Just replace the the api link in your widget.